# Displaying an image saved in a variable in Vue 3

Tags: python, django, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3

I have an application based on Vue 3 and Django REST. The application displays songs in a database, and is also supposed to display the cover images of the songs' respective albums. I have the cover images in the file system of the server and can access them via Django, and hand them out via a FileResponse when an API request comes in. I receive them in the Frontend and save the image to a variable. However, when I want to then display the image in an  tag, it just looks like this:

[image: What it currently looks like]

I want the gray boxes to display the album cover art instead. What's weird is that my browser receives the images from the API and displays them correctly:

[image: What the Browser gets]

(I know that the cover art is incorrect for the songs, that's not the point here).

The API (Django REST):

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def img_api(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.GET['id'] == 'undefined':
            return HttpResponse(
                HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', Song.objects.none()), content_type='application/json'))
        if 'id' in request.GET:
            query = request.GET['id']
            song = Song.objects.filter(song_id=query).first()
            try:
                img = open(os.path.join(SONG_PATH, song.song_image_file), 'rb')
                if song.song_image_file.endswith(".png"):
                    return FileResponse(img, content_type='image/png')
                return FileResponse(img, content_type='image/jpeg')  # file is closed automatically
            except FileNotFoundError:
                return HttpResponse(HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', Song.objects.none()), content_type='application/json'))
            except PermissionError:
                return HttpResponse(HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', Song.objects.none()), content_type='application/json'))
        return HttpResponse(HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', Song.objects.none()), content_type='application/json'))
    return HttpResponse(HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', Song.objects.none()), content_type='application/json'))
```

The Vue 3 component `SongBox.vue` with Tailwindcss:

```
<script setup>
</script>

<script>
  import axios from "axios";

  export default {
    name: "SongBox",
    props: ['song'],
    methods: {
      async getImage() {
        this.image = await axios.get(this.$hostname + 'img?id=' + this.song.pk)
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.getImage()
    },
    data() {
      return {
        image: []
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="song" class="flex w-1/3 flex-wrap px-3 -mb-12">
    <div class="w-full px-2">
      <div class="relative overflow-hidden bg-cover bg-no-repeat" style="background-position: 50%">
        <img class="block w-full h-full rounded-lg object-cover object-center" :src="this.image"/>
        <div class="absolute rounded-lg bottom-0 right-0 left-0 top-0 h-full w-full bg-black bg-fixed opacity-50 overflow-hidden"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="relative inset-y-[-20%] bottom-5 hidden py-5 text-center text-white md:block">
        <p class="text-xl">{{ song.fields.song_name }}</p>
        <p class="text-base">{{ song.fields.song_artist }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

It seems a bit like the frontend renders the SongBox component before the request for the image is answered, but then Vue also doesn't update the rendered SongBox. What do I need to change s.t. Vue renders the SongBoxes correctly?

Also, I'm not sure if I'm handling the images correctly here, since I have found no one else doing it this way. The paths to the songs are definately correct, as seen by that the browser receives the correct image.

I have tried already to pass the images via props from parent components down to the SongBox, but that also didn't work. I'm expecting the received images to render in the SongBox instead of the gray background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your network tab is a bit misleading.  What the GET actually retrieves is the raw image data. The network tab is just generating a preview based on the data.  Assigning this data directly to the `src` attribute of an img element will not work.  `src` only accepts URLs.  You need to convert your response

```js
async getImage() {
  const response = await axios.get(
    this.$hostname + "img?id=" + this.song.pk,
    { responseType: "blob" }
  );
  this.image = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
},
```

Comment: Works exactly like that, thanks!